# JDBI -> Reading MySql DATETIME into the java.sql.Date or similiar

Tags: java, mysql, jdbi

I have a field in a table in **MySQL** which is of type of DATETIME.
I'm going to simply read and use it via JDBI.

So in Mysql:

```
> desc user;
....
birth_date      datetime 
.....
```

In the App layer, I have tried very different scenarios like the following:

```java
    @SqlQuery("select birth_date from user where user_id = :userId")
    java.sql.Date fetchDateOfBirthForUser(@Bind("userId")final Long userId);
```

or

```java
    @SqlQuery("select birth_date from user where user_id = :userId")
    java.util.Date fetchDateOfBirthForUser(@Bind("userId")final Long userId);
```

or

```java
    @SqlQuery("select birth_date from user where user_id = :userId")
    java.sql.Timestamp fetchDateOfBirthForUser(@Bind("userId")final Long userId);
```

or even

```java
    @SqlQuery("select birth_date from user where user_id = :userId")
    Long fetchDateOfBirthForUser(@Bind("userId")final Long userId);
```

---

**UPDATE 1**:
I'm getting the following error, and not the null value!

```sh
    org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.NoSuchMapperException: No mapper registered for type java.util.Date
```

And this was when I used `java.util.Date`. If I use any other type which I mentioned, I get the same error: `No mapper registered for type X`

Why is that?

---

**UPDATE 2**:

Using the mappers (Timestamp and java.sql.Date) gives me the `NullPointerException`.

The value in the DB, as I mentioned before is `DATETIME`.

Now I have the following code calling the mapper:

```java
@SqlQuery("select birth_date from user where user_id = :userId")
@UseRowMapper(DateMatter.class)
java.sql.Date fetchDateOfBirthForUser(@Bind("userId")final Long userId);
```

And the DateMapper class:

```java
public class DateMatter implements RowMapper<Date> {
  @Override
    public Date map(ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
        return rs.getDate("birth");
    }
}
```

I have used `rs.getDate()`, `rs.getLong()`, and `rs.getTimestamp()` method. All leads to NPE.

Now when I call the method `dao.fetchDateOfBirthForUser(<user_id>);` I get the **NullPointerException**

---

**lAST UPDATE**
The solution was much unexpected. I was pointing to another DB from the application, and were querying another DB to verify!

Comment: JDBI under the hood registers needed mappers for `java.sql.Timestamp`/`java.time.*` classes, so could you check your DB, maybe there is no such value? Also, which JDBI version are you using?

Comment: FYI, the `java.sql.Date`, `java.until.Date`, and `Timestamp` classes are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310, and supported in JDBC 4.2 and later.

Comment: @YuriiMelnychuk The field is mandatory and should not be null (doubled check this in DB too). The JDBI version is 3.8.2

Comment: @BasilBourque You are right... but that also did not solve my issue. I still get the null value when calling for some unknown reason

Comment: @semej Column can be mandatory, but make sure that query itself is returning any result. Also, it would be better if you could provide minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code with the issue.

Comment: @YuriiMelnychukThe value is there, I did the query with DB itself and the value is there

Comment: @YuriiMelnychuk I have updated the post => The error is `No mapper registered` as you can see from the updated post.

Comment: @BasilBourqueI have updated the post => The error is `No mapper registered` as you can see from the updated post.

Comment: @semej Yes, `java.util.Date` is not preconfigured out of the box (but can be easily added via custom mapper), but did you try classes from `java.time.*` or `java.sql.Timestamp`, if there is any error, what it is?

Comment: @YuriiMelnychuk The last time I used custom mapper (which gave me the null value), I used `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date` and `Long`. Let me build the mapper with these two that you mentioned and give you the feedback.

Comment: @YuriiMelnychuk I updated the question. I get NPE when using the mappers.

Comment: @semej If you encounter exception, it is much more informative to provide stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm, that everything should work as expected, see code below, which works without a problem.
You would better check the data in database itself, it is possible that the problem is related to that.

```java
import org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.mapper.RowMapper;
import org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.StatementContext;
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.SqlObjectPlugin;
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.config.RegisterRowMapper;
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.customizer.Bind;
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.statement.SqlQuery;
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.statement.SqlScript;
import org.jdbi.v3.sqlobject.statement.SqlUpdate;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.MySQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;

@Testcontainers
class DatetimeMysqlTest {

    @Container
    private static final MySQLContainer mysql = new MySQLContainer<>();

    interface Dao {

        @SqlScript("CREATE TABLE user (user_id integer, birth_date datetime)")
        void create();

        @SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO user (user_id, birth_date) VALUES (:userId, now())")
        void insert(@Bind("userId") int userId);

        @SqlQuery("SELECT birth_date from user WHERE user_id = :userId")
        java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp(@Bind("userId") int userId);

        @SqlQuery("SELECT birth_date from user WHERE user_id = :userId")
        java.time.LocalDateTime timeLocalDate(@Bind("userId") int userId);

        @RegisterRowMapper(DateMatter.class)
        @SqlQuery("SELECT birth_date from user WHERE user_id = :userId")
        java.util.Date utilDate(@Bind("userId") int userId);

        class DateMatter implements RowMapper<Date> {
            @Override
            public java.util.Date map(ResultSet rs, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
                return rs.getDate("birth_date");
            }
        }

    }

    @Test
    void testDatetime() {
        var jdbcUrl = mysql.getJdbcUrl();
        var dao = Jdbi.create(jdbcUrl, mysql.getUsername(), mysql.getPassword())
            .installPlugin(new SqlObjectPlugin())
            .onDemand(Dao.class);
        dao.create();
        dao.insert(42);

        System.out.println(dao.sqlTimestamp(42));
        System.out.println(dao.timeLocalDate(42));
        System.out.println(dao.utilDate(42));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2021-02-25 12:34:05.0
2021-02-25T12:34:05
2021-02-25
```

Project dependencies

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbi3-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbi3-sqlobject</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Dear Yurii, Thanks for all of your help. The solution was much unexpected. I was pointing to another DB from the application, and were querying another DB to verify! Kind of stupid.